# ~/.felix folder contains massive number of files

Tags: matlab, osgi, apache-felix

On one of the accounts we use on a cluster there is a hidden folder in the home directory:

`/home/user/.felix/`

This contains a huge number of directories:

```
[user@gateway .felix]$ ls | head -10
osgi-cache1050e0f4_15774cb91f4_-7ffe
osgi-cache-1063880a_15289337854_-7ffe
osgi-cache-10716929_155ac249b99_-7ffe
osgi-cache-1076af32_1567b76f77c_-7ffe
osgi-cache10fdd858_15288297a76_-7ffe
osgi-cache1145761a_1567b157a97_-7ffe
osgi-cache-1158de5c_15775794758_-7ffe
osgi-cache-117b5c79_1577655ca87_-7ffe
osgi-cache-1188faa3_154532959fc_-7fff
osgi-cache11bf2822_1528906f443_-7ffe
```

In each of these folders:

`osgi-cache-37166e7_1545cb3b7e0_-7ffe/bundle10`

`[user@gateway bundle4]$ cat bundle.location 
reference:file:/gpfs22/local/centos6/matlab/2013a/java/jar/toolbox/bioinfo.jar`

So I'm thinking these files are created by `matlab` somehow.

This `.felix` folder contains about ~150k files which is causing us to go over our quota of 300k files. Is there a way to:

1. disable the creation of these files
2. clean them up in a safe way (maybe a cron)
3. possible move the location of where these files are created?

Comment: MATLAB does not (AFAIK) create any file unless you told it to. My guess is that the user has code that saves everything in a lot of files. Why not just contact the user? My guess that as an admin in a cluster, you'd want to limit the creation of files.

Answer (score 1):

Technically its the `apache-felix` bundle cache (http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-usage-documentation.html) and I'm afraid there's no safe way to remove any of these without contacting the user (even when migrating the path).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Matlab is creating about 7k files in /tmp/.felix. The space usage is pretty minimal (184k).  I was able to delete them by:

```
find /tmp/.felix -user <my username> -exec rm -r {} \;
```

But when I run my Matlab code it recreates many (all?) of the files.  So at least in the Matlab usage case it seems relatively safe to delete them, but I could imagine there being problems if this info is actively being updated.

Digging into the Felix docs a bit (mentioned in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776971/3448121)), I google "Felix bundle cache", and find that this is used to store pointers to Java jar files, and perhaps to state as well. There are indeed parameters that you can configure to control the location and flushing of this cache. [configuring Felix bundle cache](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-bundle-cache.html#configuring-default-behavior)

Mathworks also has [Matlab specific suggestions](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/364300-change-felix-osgi-cache-directory).  In the case mentioned there, this seemed to be triggered by plotting.  Names in the stack trace there suggest it may have to do with implementation of key bindings (keyboard shortcuts).

Rob

Comment: There is no mention of `/tmp` in the question. Did you mean to say something else? Or is this related somehow? You might want to clarify this Answer.

Comment: Good call.  I have edited to incorporate that and also other followup info.  I hadn't noticed the mention of ~/.felix, though it's still Matlab and .felix, so probably related.  I now think the actual problem I'm running into is the root filesystem being out of space, though 7k files for no known purpose seems a little gratuitous to my old school usage standards.

Comment: Fair enough. You might want to review how this answer fits with others, especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776971/1531971 Are you adding to that in some manner? Is this advice here contrary to or in alignment with that answer, and the Apache docs it references?